# Android Back Button behavior when going back through Activity / Fragment history

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app with 3 activities:

- StartActivity: Handles the login stuff and starts the MainActivity if everything is ok
- MainActivity: Has a NavigationDrawer and the user can surf through the app. All content is displayed in a Fragment, that gets started by the MainActivity
- SearchableActivity: The MainActivity's ActionBar has a search action which starts a seach query. This query is sent to this activity, which just displays some search results

Problem:
Pressing the back button does not go back through the Fragment history, although I think it should do this. The MainActivitiy uses the following method to start new Fragments:

```
protected void displayFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mainContentLayout, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

Instead of opening the last Fragment, the app simply opens the last activity (in the case of MainActivity always the StartActivity).

What am I doing wrong, if I simply want the "default behavior" without hacking an own solution?

I started implementing an own solution to hack around: The MaiNActivity overrides the onBackPressed function and manually pops up the last Fragment from the stack. When the count is too small I finish the app, so that my StartActivity isn't called again. But this does not work if I want to go back for example from SearchableActivity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count > 0) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
    } else {
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's pretty easy. If the count of the FragmentManager backstack is smaller than one, I can simply call

```
 super.onBackPressed()
```

which will just pop up the next activity in the back stack. This way, when the user presses the back button I pop up fragments as long as there are fragments, and when the fragment stack is empty I start popping up activities.

Answer (score 0):

Override onKeyDown() and handle the event

Comment: How can this help me?